# How do I take out a value from a table in lua?

Tags: lua

Now lets say I got a table like this

```
items = {
{ ["name"] = 'item1', ["prop"] = 'prop1'},
{ ["name"] = 'item2', ["prop"] = 'prop2'},
{ ["name"] = 'item3', ["prop"] = 'prop3'} 
}
```

If I where do take out the "prop" by the "name", how can I do that?

Comment: things like that can be learned by reading the Lua manual and doing beginners tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function that does something like this for a given name:

```
for k,v in pairs(items) do
  if v.name == "item2" then
    print(v.prop)
  end
end
```

Or you use a table with the item names as keys to map those values.

Instead of

```
items = {["name"] = "item1"}
```

you can simply write

```
items = {name = "item"}
```

btw.

Comment: that prints all the current props.
Yeah i know that you can type it like that, it is just my style of coding :)

Comment: @Wilmer no, it only prints the prop of items named "item2". Your tendons will punish you for this style of coding one day ;)

Comment: My bad, thanks dude! My style looks more cleaner tbh >;D,